# Nested Radio elements are treated like they are all on the same level on the DOM

Tags: html, css, radio-button, accessibility

I have an accessibility conundrum. I made my own custom radio buttons, and I'm trying to make them accessible friendly.

I have nested radio buttons. There is a parent, where you select the type of pet you want, and then a sub-radio section with all the pet accessories to choose from, and a third selection for the color of the accessory.

The problem is that when you use the arrow keys to navigate, it automatically starts walking through the sub-options. There is no way to tab through.

```html
<fieldset>
<form role="radiogroup">
    <div role="radio" aria-checked={selected} checked="selected">
        <div>
          <label>
            <input role="radio" type="radio">
            <div class="icon">
                icon here
            </div>
          </label>
        <div>
        <label>
          Cat
        </label>
      </div>
      <div role="radiogroup">
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="collar">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Collar</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="leash">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Leash</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="Toy">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Toy</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div role="radio" aria-checked={selected} checked="selected">
        <div>
          <label>
            <input role="radio" type="radio">
            <div class="icon">
                icon here
            </div>
          </label>
        <div>
        <label>
          Cat
        </label>
      </div>
      <div role="radiogroup">
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="collar">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Collar</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="leash">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Leash</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="Toy">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Toy</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div role="radio" aria-checked={selected} checked="selected">
        <div>
          <label>
            <input role="radio" type="radio">
            <div class="icon">
                icon here
            </div>
          </label>
        <div>
        <label>
          Dog
        </label>
      </div>
      <div role="radiogroup">
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="collar">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Collar</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="leash">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Leash</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div aria-checked={selected} checked={selected} role="radio">
          <div aria-label="Toy">
            <div>
              <label>
                <input role="radio" type="radio"/>
                <div>Toy</div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
 </form>
 </fieldset>
```

I know that it looks like an insane amount of divs, there are specific styles on each one that are critical to the layout.

To keep it simple I left off the color aspect because the problem still appears with just one of the nested elements.

https://whatsock.com/training/matrices/

https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20160317/examples/radio/radio.html

Thinking of trying aria-owns and aria-activedecendents but after much wrestling having no luck there either. 
https://tink.uk/using-the-aria-owns-attribute/
https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties#aria-activedescendant

The screen reader announces the labels correctly, but I would expect that you would need to navigate through the parent radio buttons, select one, and THEN navigate into the children radio set, but instead it acts as if all of them are on the same level.

So when you get to the first parent option, the suboption opens up, and as you navigate you need to navigate through all of the children to get to the second parent option.

I don't necessarily need a solution, advice for this situation or something to look for would be helpful.

This is how I want it to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/15y2tb0L/2/

Comment: Do you have a demo page somewhere ? Your code seem complicated. But quickly: `<input role=radio/>` => redundant; `<div role=radio>` is probably not a good idea, try to keep the functioning of the original radio; radio groups selection/focus are managed by id and name, not automatically with the `<div role=radiogroup>`.

Comment: @QuentinC thanks for that. I'll try to clean up the code a bit and take out the redundancies there. I did find that the solution was in the input `names` as answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a JSFiddle that has nested radio buttons here: http://jsfiddle.net/15y2tb0L/2/

By taking a look at the fiddle and comparing with my solution, I realized that the `name` element was key. When I mapped the different level of options to specific names, it solved the ADA issue.

See Fiddle, but the basic takeaway is that the parents share the same name like `name0`, the children share `name1` and the children's children share `name2`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add `tabindex="0"` to your main radio inputs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't change much. They are still all getting keyboard focus, so that isn't the problem.